# Gson.toJson() ignores @SerializedName for release build with minify option enabled

Tags: android, gson, minify, android-r8

Model to serialize:

```
data class Settings(
    @SerializedName("custom_field_name_1")
    val field1: Int,

    @SerializedName("custom_field_name_2")
    val field2: Int,
   
    ...
```

Code to serialize:

```
gson.toJson(settings).also {
    Log.i("TEST", "settingsToJson $it")
}
```

In release build (with `minifyEnabled`): I get:

> settingsToJson
> {"a":7,"b":0,"c":0,"d":"{"a":8,"b":30}","e":10,"f":1.0,"g":false,"h":1,"i":1,"j":5,"k":0,"l":false,"m":0.0}

How can I fix it?

It seems it works only for deserialization (json string to Object) but not otherwise

Comment: Did you add the [GSON proguard rules](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/main/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg) to proguard-rules.pro file?

Comment: I suggest migrating away from GSON. Especially when project is kotlin based.

Comment: @Pawel yeah, already migrating my old project to datastore + kotlinx ser + protobuf lib. Just need a hotfix for current versions on the google play. Anyway I have added `@Keep` for such models. But yeah it seems with GSON we should have used `-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * { @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName <fields>; }` for proguard rules

Comment: @user924, if that solved your issue, could you please add an answer to your question here? As side note: Future Gson versions will include ProGuard / R8 configuration by default, see https://github.com/google/gson/blob/main/gson/src/main/resources/META-INF/proguard/gson.pro